# Algorithm for unique combinations

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I've been trying to find a way to get a list of unique combinations from a list of objects nested in a container. Objects within the same group cannot be combined. Objects will be unique across all the groups

Example:

```
Group 1: (1,2)
Group 2: (3,4)
```

Result

```
1
2
3
4
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
```

If we add another group like so:

```
Group 1: (1,2)
Group 2: (3,4)
Group 3: (5,6,7)
```

The result would be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
2,3
2,4
2,5
2,6
2,7
3,5
3,6
3,7
4,5
4,6
4,7
1,3,5
1,3,6
1,3,7
1,4,5
1,4,6
1,4,7
2,3,5
2,3,6
2,3,7
2,4,5
2,4,6
2,4,7
```

I may have missed a combination above, but the combinations mentioned should be enough indication.

I have a possibility of having up  7 groups, and 20 groups in each object.

I'm trying to avoid having code that knows that it's doing combinations of doubles, triples, quadruples etc, but I'm hitting a lot of logic bumps along the way.

To be clear, I'm not asking for code, and more for an approach, pseudo code or an indication would do great.

**UPDATE**
Here's what I have after seeing those two answers.

**From @Servy's answer:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        var defaultArray = new[] { default(T) };

        return sequences.Select(sequence =>
                sequence.Select(item => item).Concat(defaultArray))
            .CartesianProduct()
            .Select(sequence =>
                sequence.Where(item => !item.Equals(default(T)))
                .Select(item => item));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
            emptyProduct,
            (accumulator, sequence) =>
                from accseq in accumulator
                from item in sequence
                select accseq.Concat(new[] { item })
            );
    }
```

**From @AK_'s answer**

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> groups)
    {

        if (groups.Count() == 0)
        {
            yield return new T[0];
        }

        if (groups.Count() == 1)
        {
            foreach (var t in groups.First())
            {
                yield return new T[] { t };
            }
        }

        else
        {
            var furtherResult = GetCombinations(groups.Where(x => x != groups.Last()));

            foreach (var result in furtherResult)
            {
                yield return result;
            }

            foreach (var t in groups.Last())
            {
                yield return new T[] { t };

                foreach (var result in furtherResult)
                {
                    yield return result.Concat(new T[] { t });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage for both**

```
List<List<int>> groups = new List<List<int>>();

        groups.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2 });
        groups.Add(new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5 });
        groups.Add(new List<int>() { 6, 7 });
        groups.Add(new List<int>() { 8, 9 });
        groups.Add(new List<int>() { 10, 11 });


        var x = groups.GetCombinations().Where(g => g.Count() > 0).ToList().OrderBy(y => y.Count());
```

What would be considered the best solution? To be honest, I am able to read what's happening with @AK_'s solution much easier (had to look for a solution on how to get Cartesian Product).

Comment: I'm not clear from your examples on the rules you are using.  What is the difference here between calculating all permutations of (1,2),(3,4) versus calculating all permutations of (1,2,3,4)? Why is 3,4 in your second result list but not the first?  (Google advice: the word you want is "permutations".)

Comment: Hint, there are `(group1->Length + 1) * (group2->Length + 1) * ... * (last_group->Length + 1) - 1` such combinations.

Comment: Actually that's a mistake, will fix.

Comment: @JacobMattison: No, it definitely isn't permutations, I never see the same result in a different order.

Comment: @JacobMattison, updated, removed (3,3) (3,4) & (4,4) Copy & paste mistake.

Comment: Ah, so the rule is that you want no more than one from each group?

Comment: In a combination, yes.

Comment: If you add "empty" to each group, and then find all combinations that way, wouldn't you have everything you need. For example, the start of your list would be (1,empty,empty). The number of combinations is then the product of list lengths minus one, as you'll have to discard the (empty, empty, empty) combination. The algorithm looks like a nested for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off consider the problem of a Cartesian Product of N sequences.  That is, every single combination of one value from each of the sequences.  [Here is a example of an implementation of that problem, with an amazing explanation](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

But how do we handle the cases where the output combination has a size smaller than the number of sequences?  Alone that only handles the case where the given sequences are the same size as the number of sequences.  Well, imagine for a second that every single input sequence has a "null" value.  That null value gets paired with every single combination of values from the other sequences (including all of *their* null values).  We can then remove these null values at the very end, and voila, we have every combination of every size.

To do this, while still allowing the input sequences to actually use the C# literal `null` values, or the default value for that type (if it's not nullable) we'll need to wrap the type.  We'll create a wrapper that wraps the real value, while also having it's own definition of a def ult/null value.  From there we map each of our sequences into a sequence of wrappers, append the actual default value onto the end, compute the Cartesian Product, and then map the combinations back to "real" values, filtering out the default values while we're at it.

If you don't want to see the actual code, stop reading here.

---

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public Wrapper(T value) { Value = value; }
    public static Wrapper<T> Default = new Wrapper<T>(default(T));
    public T Value { get; private set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Foo<T>
    (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    return sequences.Select(sequence =>
            sequence.Select(item => new Wrapper<T>(item))
            .Concat(new[] { Wrapper<T>.Default }))
        .CartesianProduct()
        .Select(sequence => 
            sequence.Where(wrapper => wrapper != Wrapper<T>.Default)
            .Select(wrapper => wrapper.Value));
}
```

Comment: won't you end up with some empty lists?

Comment: Yes you would, I had to filter them out later on.

Comment: @AK_ You'll have exactly one.

Comment: @MatthewGrima AK's solution has quite a lot of problems.  He's iterating sequences multiple times, and when those sequences that are being iterated aren't simple things like lists, but complex sequences like recursive calls to the method itself at every single depth it ends up re-computing a *huge* amount of the work over and over again.  This results in it scaling much, much, much worse as the size of the input data increases.  For some perspective, using 9 lists of size 2, and executing 10 times, my program (on my machine) takes five seconds, AK's takes 13 *minutes* and 29 seconds.

Comment: I tried running both with 7 lists of 20 numbers (maximum as the question mentions). Yours gave me OutOfMemoryException, Whereas AK_'s has been running for quite a while now but has not yet broken down.

I've not tried his updated answer yet.

Comment: @MatthewGrima That's a *huge* amount of data, given the complexity of this algorithm even in the best case.  The number of records in the output for that initial input is: 558545864083284007.  That's...a lot

Comment: That size of the lists and number of lists is highly unlikely but my requirements state that maximum. Calculating the size of output didn't come to mind to be honest (it should have). I will probably need a requirements alteration :)

Comment: @Servy, can you help me out a bit, is there any equation I can use to get the number of combinations by any chance?

Comment: @Servy Its 21^7 not 7^21 its the same as arranging 21 numbers in 7 places not the other way around... so thats only : 1,801,088,541 ...

Comment: @MatthewGrima I just gave you the equation above... anyway, it should be doable but on a 64 bit process on a machine with plenty of memory. i would also consider doing it, either with plain arrays, or immutable lists (which would eat up a lot less memory)

Comment: @MatthewGrima you can make this run in parallel, but is very not trivial do do it, and its even more not trivial to do it in a way that will have better performance.

Comment: After some different tests with some big lists, the solution from @Servy is much faster. 7 lists, with 15 numbers in each takes 58 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In C#

this is actually a monad... I think...

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> foo (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> groups)
{

    if (groups.Count == 0)
    {
        return new List<List<int>>();
    }

    if (groups.Count == 1)
    {
        foreach(van num in groups.First())
        {
            return yield new List<int>(){num};
        }
    }

    else
    {
        var furtherResult = foo(groups.Where(x=> x != groups.First()));

        foreach (var result in furtherResult)
        {
            yield  return result;
        }

        foreach(van num in groups.First())
        {
            yield return new List<int>(){num};

            foreach (var result in furtherResult)
            {
                yield return result.Concat(num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

a better version:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> foo<T> (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> groups)
    {
        if (groups.Count() == 0)
        {
            return new List<List<T>>();
        }

        else
        {
            var firstGroup = groups.First();

            var furtherResult = foo(groups.Skip(1));

            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> myResult =  from x in firstGroup
                select new [] {x};

            myResult = myResult.Concat(  from x      in firstGroup 
                                       from result in furtherResult
                                       select result.Concat(new T[]{x}));

            myResult = myResult.Concat(furtherResult);

            return myResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MatthewGrima my solution is sort of more efficient because I don't add and remove the null element. Anyway I think you should test\ play around with both. Servy's code can be re-factored to be a lot more succinct and readable than mine, even more so if C# was a proper programming language...

Comment: @MatthewGrima I thought a little bit about it, and i think you dont need the second if in my code (if the list has one element. I dont have an environment to test it right now...

Comment: @MatthewGrima I edited and added a more "Linqy" version, and it doesnt produce any empty lists... have fun...

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as the answer, as I ended up using it. Will try your second example later on.

Comment: @AK_ You think this solution is more efficient?  This solution is *orders of magnitude* less efficient.  The code is doing *tons* of *really* inefficient things, most important of which is that it's iterating sequences *many* times, and those sequences aren't just lists, to which iterating repeatedly isn't a huge issues, they're recursive calls to the method itself which are complex compositions of many LINQ operations.  For some perspective, using 9 lists of size 2, and executing 10 times, my program (on my machine) takes five seconds, yours takes 13 *minutes* and 29 seconds.

Comment: Oh, and that's not to mention the *numerous* compiler errors all over your code...

Comment: @Servy i just tested the seconed code snippet with 10 lists of 2 elements, **and then summing everything**, executing 10 times, and it took 8 seconds...

Comment: @Servy Just tested your version, and it takes 15 seconds... so one of us is doing something wrong...

Comment: @AK_ Now execute your first solution.

Comment: @Servy but the issue there is with the yields...  there is a reason i posted the better version...

Comment: @AK_ The fact that you had a recursive iterator block is indeed a part of what made that code problematic, but it really pales in comparison to the repeated iteration of complex queries.  And keep in mind the OP is using your first query (after modifying it to make it compile).